# Linq query to select single string from multiple List<string>

Tags: c#, string, linq

I am having a hard time understanding why I am getting the results that I am.

I have two lists of strings:

```
var list1 = new List<String> {"item 1", "item 2"};
var list2 = new List<String> { "item 3", "item 4" };
```

Version 1 - Output: "item 2"

```
var item =
            from x in (list1.Concat(list2))
            where x.EndsWith("2")
            select x;

        Console.WriteLine(item.First());
```

Version 2 - Output: "i"

```
var item =
            from x in (list1.Concat(list2))
            where x.EndsWith("2")
            select x.First();

        Console.WriteLine(item.First());
```

Version 3 - Output: "System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereEnumerableIterator`1[System.String]"

```
var item =
            from x in (list1.Concat(list2))
            where x.EndsWith("2")
            select x;

        Console.WriteLine(item);
```

Given that version 2 outputs "i", I would expect version 3 to output "item 2". Why is this behavior occurring?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In version 3, `select x` is returning a *sequence* of strings that match your critera; it just happens to be a sequence with one item in it.

`Console.WriteLine` internally calls `.ToString()` on whatever you pass into it. Since there is no meaningful string representation for `IEnumerable<T>`, the default in .NET is to print the string name of the type.

Based on your wording, I think part of your confusion does come from a misunderstanding of why version 2 works the way it does. In version 2, `select x.First()` is actually a bit of a quirk/coincidence, because a string is *also* an `IEnumerable<char>`, so you can do LINQ operations on the string. `.First()` returns the first element of that `char` sequence, for each result that matches your criteria. So you're saying:

> "For each element which matches my criteria, select the first character, and then return the sequence of all the first characters for the matches."

So in fact, `item` in version 2 is an `IEnumerable<char>` with one element in it. Calling `Console.WriteLine()` on an `IEnumerable<char>` will just print the chars in order. So you get "i".

(note: I see after I answered this, the question was edited to call `.First()` both inside the projection and on the result, so the bit about passing `IEnumerable<char>` to `Console.WriteLine` isn't totally relevant anymore)

Keep in mind LINQ is pretty much about working with sets until you explicitly reduce them down. For example, `Select` is simply a projection or transformation. It returns the same number of items that were passed to it, transformed. `Where` reduces down the set, but it's still a set.

Comment: +1 This is the only other answer I've seen that recognizes the question is about the 3rd case, and not the 2nd

Answer (score 2):

Your Version 2 is selecting first item/char from the string `x.First()`, whereas your first version is selecting first item from the result set-> First string.

Version 1 is like - **Select First Item from the Result Set**

```
var item =  (from x in (list1.Concat(list2))
            where x.EndsWith("2")
            select x).First(); //First complete string will be selected
```

and version 2 is like- **Select First Item from a string in result set**

```
var item =  from x in (list1.Concat(list2))
            where x.EndsWith("2")
            select x.First(); //only first char will be selected for string
```

Your third case is selecting an `IEnumerable<string>`, so when you call `Console.WriteLine`, it calls the default implementation of `ToString` and thus you get

> "System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereEnumerableIterator`1[System.String]"

Comment: Your examples are very helpful here. So, will a select without a .First() or .Single() always return a set as opposed to a single element?

Comment: @JoeBauer, yes. Exactly.

Comment: @JoeBauer, one more thing, Even if there are no rows matching the criteria `select` would return an empty collection/set.

Answer (score 0):

When using `First()` you are materializing the list, causing the iterator to execute. That is eager execution. Your third version uses `select` which does not materialize the list abd uses `Defeered Execution` which returns an iterator, hence calling `ToString()` on it returning the iterators name

Answer (score 0):

Because `Where` returns an `IEnumerable`.

You have written the equivalent of:

```
var whoKnows = list1.Concat(list2).Where(x => x.EndsWith("2"));
Console.WriteLine(whoKnows);
```

The `ToString` of a collection just returns the class name.

Answer (score 0):

The type of the `x` in your  Version 2 is `String`. The type of `item` in Version 1 is IEnumerable.

So your Version 2 return a list of characters which are the first characters of each string. In your Version 1, `item.First()` return the first element of the result set which is a string.

Answer (score 0):

```
//This raise a exception if no item found
var item=list1.Concat(list2).First(i => i.EndsWith("2"));
//this return default value (null) if no item found
var item2 = list1.Concat(list2).FirstOrDefault(i => i.EndsWith("2"));
```